# How to interrupt function when cancel from UI in Python?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I have the function extract data like this:

```
@controller.route('/scrap_all_categories')
def scrap_all_categories():   
    result = ETL_jobs.extract_all_category(url, conn)
    return result
```

Extract_all_category is a function which extracts data from a website using BeautifulSoup. So it takes about 30 min to finish and it runs until the job is done without using interrupt key.
And I need create a function to cancel this process. Which functions in Python I can use to interrupt this job.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with ```return``` ```sys.exit()``` or ```raise SystemExit```, 3 statements to break your function ?

Comment: Yes, I tried sys.exit(), but it not working. os.exit() interrupt whole application. I just want to interrupt a function.

Comment: If you want to interrupt your function, then just place a ```return``` statement when a specific condition is encountered in your function.

Comment: Hi, I call interrupt scrap function from other function, cancel_job. And this function can work when scrapping function just run about 10 minutes.